# std::atomic<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point> can not compile

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I need `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` field which I want to write from one thread and read from another thread. If I declare it as is my code compiles without any errors.

But to make my field visible in another thread I surround it with `std::atomic` like this `std::atomic<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point>` and now I have following compilation error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic:167:7: error: function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >]’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘constexpr std::atomic<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > >::atomic()’
       atomic() noexcept = default;
```

How should I declare `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` field which I write from one thread and read from another (to make sure that "reading thread" sees last value)?

Comment: `atomic` can only be used with trivially copyable types, and as far as I can tell there's no guarantee that `time_point` is trivially copyable.

Comment: T.C. says is right. And you can use [std::is_trivial or other](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) test it...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your choices:

- forget about making it atomic and use a mutex to serialise access
- pick some integral unit of time (e.g. milliseconds since epoch) and convert to/from that on the fly, storing the integral value in some integral type you've worked out has sufficient capacity to cover the range of dates you're handling (perhaps `std::atomic_ullong`)
- (nutty suggestion removed)

Comment: thanks I will try second approach, something like ` duration_cast<nanoseconds>(time_point.time_since_epoch()).count()`

Comment: Tony, while you first two bullet points are good, I cannot upvote *any* answer that comes within a whisker of seeming to suggest the merest possibility that UB may be acceptable :-)

Comment: "embrace undefined behavior" I love that phrase, I think I need it on a t-shirt. With a design that implies how badass people embracing UB are, always living on the edge. Basically the BASE jumpers of coding 

Answer (score 13):

Use `std::atomic<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration>` and set it to time_point::time_since_epoch() when storing; when loading, construct a time_point from the duration in the atomic with the standard conversion constructor for that.  It's a little irritating that this is necessary, but at least it's type safe and there are no uncertainties about the size or resolution of the atomic type.

Comment: Don't you mean `std::atomic<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::rep>`? Is there any guarantee that `std::chrono::duration` is trivially copyable?

Comment: Even `rep` is not guaranteed to be trivially copyable. From https://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration#general paragraph 2: *Rep shall be an arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type.*