# C++ ThreadSafe time counting class

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, thread-safety, mutex

I am trying to build a simple threadsafe time counter class. The code I managed to write is the follwing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

/* Get timestamp in microseconds */
static inline uint64_t micros()
{
    return (uint64_t)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

class Timer
{
public:
    explicit Timer() = default;


    /**
     * @brief Restart the counter
     */
    void Restart()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        {
            this->_PreviousUs = micros();
            this->_IsRunning = true;
        }
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
    }

    /**
     * @brief Stop the timer
     */
    void Stop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        {
            this->_IsRunning = false;
        }
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
    }


    /**
     * @brief Check whether counter is started or not
     * @return true if timer is running, false otherwise
     */
    bool IsRunning()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        bool tmp = _IsRunning;
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calculate number of elapsed milliseconds from current timestamp
     * @return Return elapsed milliseconds
     */
    uint64_t ElapsedMs()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        uint64_t tmp = _PreviousUs;
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
        return ( millis() - (tmp/1000u) );
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calculate number of elapsed microseconds from current timestamp
     * @return Return elapsed microseconds
     */
    uint64_t ElapsedUs()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
        uint64_t tmp = _PreviousUs;
        mlock.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
        return ( micros() - tmp );
    }

private:
    /** Timer's state */
    bool _IsRunning = false;
    /** Thread sync for read/write */
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cond;
    /** Remember when timer was stated */
    uint64_t _PreviousUs = 0;
};
```

The usage is simple. I just create a global variable then access it from few different threads.

```
/* global variable */
Timer timer;
..............................
/* restart in some methods */
timer.Restart();
...............................
/* From some other threads */
if(timer.IsRunning())
{
    // retrieve time since Restsrt() then do something
    timer.ElapsedMs();

    // Restart eventually
    timer.Restart();
}
```

It is working under Linux and is fine for now. But the pice of code which is worrying me is this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(_mutex);
uint64_t tmp = _PreviousUs;
mlock.unlock();
_cond.notify_one();
return ( micros() - tmp );
```

I have to create a temporary variable everytime I check for the elapsed time for the sake of the "thread safety". 
Is there any way to improve my code and to keep it thread safe at the same time?

PS: I know that I can use only the function `micros()` to count time as simple as possible but my plans are to develop this class further in the future.

Later edit: My question is not really how do I get the timestamps. My question is how do I read/write safe `_PreviousUs` given that the same instance of the Timer class will be shared across multiple threads?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to store the timestamp in an `std::atomic<uint64_t>` ?  No need for complicated thread synchronization then.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't understand why you keep timestamps as untyped integers. The whole chrono thing is there to avoid this dread!

Comment: Also, why do you drop the type safety of `std::chrono` and going back to C-style programming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::atomic<std::chrono::high\_resolution\_clock::time\_point> can not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364456/stdatomicstdchronohigh-resolution-clocktime-point-can-not-compile)

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't look right.

There is an example how to measure time in [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#include <thread>

void f()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // floating-point duration: no duration_cast needed
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> fp_ms = t2 - t1;

    // integral duration: requires duration_cast
    auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    // converting integral duration to integral duration of shorter divisible time unit:
    // no duration_cast needed
    std::chrono::duration<long, std::micro> int_usec = int_ms;

    std::cout << "f() took " << fp_ms.count() << " ms, "
              << "or " << int_ms.count() << " whole milliseconds "
              << "(which is " << int_usec.count() << " whole microseconds)" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what i wanted to achieve actually was to wrap all this stuff inside a class.

Comment: @caffeine Wrap it then. But throw away all that thread-safety nonsense.